# How can I hide env variables and some standard passwords in build/static/11.23e.. .js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**Issue** : when I  build my code using npm run build:dev (as per package.json) how we configured we are getting a build file in app and when I am checking in browser I am able to see this in one of minified.js files

```
e.debuglog = function(n) {
                if (y(o) && (o = Object({
                        NODE_ENV: "production",
                        PUBLIC_URL: "",
                        WDS_SOCKET_HOST: void 0,
                        WDS_SOCKET_PATH: void 0,
                        WDS_SOCKET_PORT: void 0,
                        REACT_APP_COURSEAPI_KEY:12345, //example
                        REACT_APP_COURSEAPI_URL: "https://stg.use.cap.pulse.pearson-intl.com
```

Now I am unable to hide secret keys from build file?
P.S: I am not pushing env variables to my version control?

Comment: Of course, they are part of your build after all. How would you expect your app to know about your API tokens if they weren't a part of the build?

Comment: @nbokmans while doing some network testing in my organization the insisted me that these things are confidential and gets a chance to hack So I am searching a way around to decrease the build size using webpack but failing to map properly in package.json and segregate by envs(prod,dev,staging,sandbox)

Comment: A common practice is to use a backend that serves as a proxy for your api calls. So, send a request without API key to your own backend, and then let your backend do a request to the actual API with the API key header added to the request

Comment: @nbokmans It's a performance flaw and it wouldn't work for all scenarios since we are communicating with different services

Comment: Okay, then don't do it. I'm not gonna argue best practices simply because you think it's a "performance flaw" (spoiler alert: it's not - if this is the bottleneck of your application, you have bigger problems to solve). Good luck finding alternative solutions that don't involve proxying requests!